# How to write a duplicate record method in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

In my Rails app I have an `invoices_controller.rb` with these actions:

```
def new
  @invoice = current_user.invoices.build(:project_id => params[:project_id])
  @invoice.build_item(current_user)
  @invoice.set_number(current_user)
end

def create
  @invoice = current_user.invoices.build(params[:invoice])    
  if @invoice.save
    flash[:success] = "Invoice created."
    redirect_to edit_invoice_path(@invoice)
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Essentially, the `new` method instantiates a new `invoice` record plus one associated `item` record.

Now, what sort of method do I need if I want to **duplicate** an existing `invoice`?

I am a big fan of Rails's RESTful approach, so I wonder if I should add a new method like

```
def duplicate

end
```

or if I can use the existing `new` method and pass in the values of the `invoice` to be duplicated there?

What is the best approach and what might that method look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naturally, you can extend RESTful routes and controllers.

To be rally RESTful, it is important to look exactly, what you want.

i.e. if you want a new invoice and use an existing one as a kind of template, then it is comparable to a `new` action, and the verb should be `GET` (get the input form). As is it based on an existing invoice, it should reference that object. After that you would `create` the new invoice in the usual way.

So in you routes:

```
resources :invoices do
  member do
    get 'duplicate'
  end
end
```

giving you a route `duplicate_invoice   GET /invoices/:id/duplicate(.format)  invoices#duplicate`

So in your view you can say

```
<%= link_to 'duplicate this', duplicate_invoice_path(@invoice) %>
```

and in your controller

```
def duplicate
  template = Invoice.find(params[:id])
  @invoice= template.duplicate # define in Invoice.duplicate how to create a dup
  render action: 'new'
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up with a mixture between `Adit`'s answer and yours since both worked equally well for me. I took the liberty to call my method `duplicate` though ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your question you can:

```
resources :invoices do
  collection do
    get 'duplicate'
  end
end
```

and with this you can do:

```
def duplicate
  # @invoice = [get the invoice]
  @invoice.clone_invoice
  render 'edit' # or 'new', depends on your needs
end
```

`clone_invoice` could be a custom method which should have a `invoice.clone` call in your custom method.

Comment: Or `dup` instead of `clone` if Rails version >= 3.1

Comment: Thanks, I ended up with something very similar, even though I think I need `member do` instead of `collection do` in my `routes.rb` file because I am dealing with single records here.

Answer (score 1):

If you question if you can use additional methods except REST, you absolutely can. Google, for example, encourage developers to use something, what they call "extended RESTful" on GoogleIO, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nyu5ZxGUfgs

So use additional method duplicate, but don't forget about "Thin controllers, fat models" approach to incapsulate your duplicating logic inside model.